# Integration Testing with a CDI Injected Principal

Tags: security, integration-testing, cdi, jboss-arquillian, websphere-liberty

I have a simple request scope bean that contains an injected Principal so that I can determine the ID of the current user.  That bean is then injected into a Servlet and the Servlet uses the bean to display the user's ID.  For example:

**The interface:**

```
public interface UserManager {

     public String getCurrentUserName();

}
```

**The  implementation:**

```
@RequestScoped
public class CdiUserManager implements UserManager {

     @Inject
     private Principal principal;

     public CdiUserManager() {

     }

     @Override
     public String getCurrentUserName() {

         String name = null;

         if(principal != null && principal.getName() != null){
              name = principal.getName();
         }

         return name;
     }

 }
```

**The servlet:**

```
@WebServlet({"/public/user", "/authenticated/user"})
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {

     @Inject
     private UserManager manager;

     public UserServlet() {
        super();
     }

     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

         response.getWriter().write("UserName: " + manager.getCurrentUserName());
     }

 }
```

The servlet is mapped for both authenticated and unauthenticated access.  I have the web.xml configured with the proper security constraints so that basic authentication is required for the authenticated URL only.

I also have an EAR file.  The application.xml in the EAR includes the web module with the servlet and managed bean as well as the security role that is defined in the web.xml.  In addition, I have an ibm-application-bnd.xml file that maps the security role in the web.xml and application.xml to the special subject ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS.

I have an empty beans.xml file in the WEB-INF directory of the WAR.

**I have two issues at the moment that I can't seem to resolve.**

1) When I access the public URL as an unauthenticated user, I would expected that either the inject Principal or the call to principal.getName() would be null or some other identifiable value...  i.e. "UNAUTHENTICATED".  Currently I get a NPE with the stack trace below.  If I access the authenticated URL and login via basic authentication, the servlet returns my user name as expected.  I'm not sure what the standard says should be returned in this case, but I would think this is a bug?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.apache.webbeans.component.BuildInOwbBean$BuildInBeanMethodHandler.invoke(BuildInOwbBean.java:273)
at [internal classes]
at org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_1.getName(Object_$$_javassist_1.java)
at com.testing.cdi.CdiUserManager.getCurrentUserName(CdiUserManager.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorHandler.invoke(InterceptorHandler.java:327)
at [internal classes]
at com.testing.cdi.CdiUserManager_$$_javassist_0.getCurrentUserName(CdiUserManager_$$_javassist_0.java)
at com.testing.cdi.UserServlet.doGet(UserServlet.java:31)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
at [internal classes]
```

2) The second issue I have is how to integration test using the injected Principal?  I'm currently using Arquillian and I've built a deployment method that looks like this:

```
 @Deployment
 public static EnterpriseArchive createDeployment() {

    EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class, CONTEXT_ROOT + ".ear");
    WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, CONTEXT_ROOT + ".war");

    war.addPackages(true, UserManager.class.getPackage());

    war.addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    war.setWebXML(new File("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml"));

    ear.setApplicationXML(new File("../testing-ear/src/main/application/META-INF/application.xml"));
    ear.addAsManifestResource(new File("../testing-ear/src/main/application/META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml"));
    ear.addAsModule(war);

    return ear;
 }
```

I'm authenticating my test user before each test case like this:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws LoginException, WSSecurityException {

    // WLP provided classes to authenticate a user.
    CallbackHandler wscbh = new WSCallbackHandlerImpl("user", "password");
    LoginContext ctx = new LoginContext("WSLogin", wscbh);
    ctx.login();

    // Set the user as the current user on the thread.
    Subject mySubject = ctx.getSubject();
    WSSubject.setRunAsSubject(mySubject);

}
```

Then in the test case, I'm checking to see if the user name is null like this:

```
@Test
public void testAuthenticatedPrincipal() throws LoginException, WSSecurityException {


    assertNull("User name should not be null.", manager.getCurrentUserName());
}
```

The execution of this test case always results in a NPE with the the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.apache.webbeans.component.BuildInOwbBean$BuildInBeanMethodHandler.invoke(BuildInOwbBean.java:273)
at org.apache.webbeans.component.BuildInOwbBean$BuildInBeanMethodHandler.invoke(BuildInOwbBean.java:267)
at org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_2.getName(Object_$$_javassist_2.java)
at com.testing.cdi.CdiUserManager.getCurrentUserName(CdiUserManager.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.InterceptorHandler.invoke(InterceptorHandler.java:327)
at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:117)
at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.invoke(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:108)
at com.testing.cdi.CdiUserManager_$$_javassist_1.getCurrentUserName(CdiUserManager_$$_javassist_1.java)
at com.testing.cdi.test.UserManagerTest.testAuthenticatedPrincipal(UserManagerTest.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$6$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:325)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ContainerTestExecuter.execute(ContainerTestExecuter.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:135)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$6.evaluate(Arquillian.java:318)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:277)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:202)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:377)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:52)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:216)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:164)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:66)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:159)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:125)
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:89)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:473)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1104)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:863)
```

In the past I've built EJB projects and integration tested them using this method.  An inject SessionContext replaces the Principal in that scenario.  Does anyone have any advice or experience on how to get this test case to run?

P.S.  I'm using the IBM JDK v1.7.1 with WebSphere Liberty Developer Edition v8.5.5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a null value is used for the principal of a user who is not logged in, e.g. HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal() returns null if the user has not been authenticated.

Therefore, I don't think it's unreasonable for the injected Principal to be null. However, the Principal is also a CDI bean which is proxied. Since you have an injected proxy object, you can't test it for nullness but when you call getName(), CDI tries to find the real Principal for the logged in user and calls getName() on it, resulting in the NullPointerException.

I realise that's not hugely helpful since you can't really use the Principal bean to check whether the user is authenticated but I don't think it's wrong.

For the Arquillian test, you could have the test run as a client, rather than on the server so you can manually call the servlet URL and provide the authentication credentials. You'd have to have the servlet print out the username and check that the response is correct on the client.

There's some information about running tests in client mode here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Test+run+modes